# Data extract UserAgent with Mac

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-extract

We are running data extract on a daily basis, recently we added the 'Include User Agent Information'.
Checking the consistency of the data we have found a user who opens the email with a Mac and clicks a link. The 'Opens.cvs' shows the following data:

```
Browser     EmailClient     OperatingSystem     Device
Firefox     Unspecified     Windows XP          PC
```

But the 'Clicks.csv' is inconsistent with this data:

```
Browser     EmailClient     OperatingSystem     Device 
Chrome      Apple Mail 1    Mac OS X 10.1       Macintosh
```

We are 100%sure that the click is related with the open.
¿Has anyone expecienced this before?

Comment: Windows XP?! No wonder it doesn't work!

Comment: in fact, the computer used to open the email was a Mac with Mac OS X 10.1 as the click tracking states. The open tracking is the one that is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Known issue oppened: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008i9hQAA&title=tracking-extract-showing-opens-in-firefox-instead-of-chrome